Delay in Initial Launch of Electron Applications
Why do applications created with Electron experience a significant delay in their initial launch, taking between 5 to 10 seconds to start, but launch quickly on subsequent runs? This delay happens again if Windows is restarted, with the first launch taking longer each time. Even Electron's own "quick start" app behaves this way after being built, but VS Code, also built with Electron, doesn't have this delay. What's the reason for this?
also i tested with empty app and just html file without any script

After examining the VS Code application and conducting various tests, the conclusion was that if the application is installed in the USER/AppData/Local/Programs/ directory, it runs at optimal speed, especially after restarting Windows.
